# Change all list items during iteration

Tags: groovy

**Problem**

I need to change all list items during a loop. Is it possible?

**Code**

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@id="id1"]//tr[td/a]'))
elements.eachWithIndex { element, index ->
    ...
    if(...) {
        ...
        i = index+1
        elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@id="id1"]//tr[td/a][position()>' + i + ']')) // new list content which must be use by loop
    }
}
```

However, new list is not used by the loop.

Can you help and explain me why?

Thanks

Regards

**EDIT 1**

I need to retrieve element everytime.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@id="dzA26"]//tr[td/a]'))
for(int i = 1; i <= elements.size(); i++) { 
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="dzA26"]//tr[td/a][' + i + ']'))
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use a for loop ?

Comment: I could. But it will solve my problem?

Comment: I think it will. Why not have a try?

Comment: I have try. But the problem is a bit complicate. Indeed, I need to update my list content because on each iteration references are lost.

Comment: Wait - I don't seem to understand. You don't want to lost the reference? then you can create a new list. Can you give some examples?

Comment: Of course. I'm using this code with Katalon (based on Selenium). When I refresh the page, references of elements are lost because page has been refreshed. A solution found is to use a `for` loop and to create WebElement inside it, but it is a bit dirty right? I update my question with an example.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all while iterating over a List, changing or removing elements is not safe to do. It can be possible, but you should avoid it. 
That's because you are trying to change the element it is currently iterating at. So the Iterator behind the '.each' closure gets confused and doesn't know where to go on after the current iteration.

If you have to change all elements with the same operation, you could use the List.collect() closure provided by groovy, which will return whatever you like into a new List.

e.g.:

```
List<WebElement> elements = elements.collect { element ->
    return element.doSomething()
}
```

**Edit 1**

After your update there is a new Problem, because it seems like you always want to update all Elements int the List.

So why don't you create the List inside the Loop, fill it, and use it, then go to the next iteration.

e.g.:

```
for(int i = 0;i < threshold; i++) {
    List<WebElement> elements = useMethodToRetrieveElementsFori(i);
    elements.each {
        // Do whatever has to be done with this element.
    }
}
```

Or after looking at it a little longer, it seems obvious to use code reflection at that point. Because you want to dig deeper into the WebElements, you should call a method that calls itself if it needs to go one step further. With your idea, you'd be stuck in an endless loop.

Or we are missing the the whole point of the question.

Comment: I updated my post with real list declaration. Can you edit your post because I don't know why I have to use `{ element ->`.